# Open Elixir Source Package?

Tags: elixir

In Ruby you can easily view the source of the gem version used in your app with:

```
$ bundle open devise
```

Is there an equivalent in Elixir?

Comment: The complete source of all dependencies should be in `deps/` after you do `mix deps.get`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Also you can easily find source code on GitHub, but certainly version of deps you have, will be in `deps/`.

Comment: @Dogbert that's pretty useful. I might choose to hide `deps/` from my text editor, I suppose, but maybe that accessibility means there is no equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Elixir equivalent of `bundle open GEM` such as `mix open DEP`.

Having a package to add a `mix open` task for example, would add little convenience because Mix dependencies are project-specific and not global. You'd have to specify the package as a dependency for every project, unless you install it as an archive.

Instead, view the source with `<editor> deps/<package>` from your project's root directory.

Comment: If you want to modify the dependency's code (for instance, to debug your usage of it), see http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/03/inspecting-changing-and-debugging-elixir-project-dependencies/.